# prove $f(\cup A) = \cup f(A)$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, predicate-logic

I know it is a simple theorem that
$$ f(\bigcup_{\gamma\in \Gamma} A_\gamma) = \bigcup_{\gamma \in \Gamma} f(A_\gamma)$$

I know how to prove it by the definition of the above things, but I want to prove it by logical proposition using $\forall, \exists$.

\begin{align}
&y \in f(\bigcup_{\gamma\in \Gamma} A_\gamma) \\
&\Leftrightarrow \exists x \in \bigcup_{\gamma\in \Gamma} A_\gamma : y=f(x)\\
&\Leftrightarrow \exists x(x \in \bigcup_{\gamma\in \Gamma} A_\gamma \wedge y=f(x) )\\
&\Leftrightarrow \exists x\{(\exists \gamma \in \Gamma: x \in A_{\gamma})\wedge y=f(x)\}
\end{align}

and then I don't know how to deal with it.

Help me to prove the theorem by using predicate logic.

*edit.

I want to prove it by predicate logic changing the word 'for some x, for all x, and, or' to '$\exists, \forall, \wedge, \vee$' and using bracket. I wrote that I know how to prove it by the definition of things.

Comment: As long as you got all the right tags...

Comment: I want to prove it by predicate logic changing the word 'for some x, for all x, and, or' to '$\exists, \forall, \wedge, \vee$' and using bracket. I wrote that I know how to prove it by the definition of things.

Comment: If you cannot see how changing "some" to $\exists$ and "and" to $\land$, then I can't help you. The only way to prove something like this equality is by appealing to the definition. Whether your wrote it as a symbolic list of sentences, or partially in words, the meaning of these remain the same.

Comment: I know things remain the same. But I don't know how to deal with it by the symbolic list of sentences. I know changing "some" to $\exists$ and "and" to $\vee$.  Using these symbols, there are non-intuitive properties in it. For example "$\exists$" with "$\wedge$" doesn't work by distribution law.

Comment: $\exists x\, \{ (\exists \gamma \in \Gamma: x \in A_{\gamma}) \land y=f(x) \}$ if and only if $\exists x : \{ \exists \gamma \in \Gamma : (x \in A_\gamma \land y = f(x)) \}$ if and only if $\exists \gamma \in \Gamma : \{\exists x : (x \in A_\gamma \land y = f(x)) \}$ if and only if $\exists \gamma \in \Gamma : y \in f(A_\gamma)$ if and only if $y \in \bigcup_{\gamma \in \Gamma} f(A_\gamma)$.

Comment: The proof relies on the fact that $\exists x\, \exists y\, A(x,y)$ is equivalent to $\exists y\, \exists x\, A(x, y)$.

Comment: thank you for the answer.